# Xamarin google maps autocomplete

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, autocomplete, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to add an autocomplete service to my custom searchbar (I'm using an entry) on Xamarin forms for my Xamarin forms map, but I haven't been able to do so.

I already tried with XLabs but didn't work and I haven't found any other solution so far.

Does Xamarin.FormsMaps include any autocomplete function? Or is there any autocomplete function already on Xamarin that I may be missing?
What do you recommend me? If you need any code or anything else, please let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Place Autocomplete in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34390423/google-place-autocomplete-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: @hvaughan3 I already saw that one, but it's an android exclusive, that's why no answer is checked on that question. Thanks tho.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a long one but here goes.... Obviously you would want to put the service calling code in a service `class` and all of the other code in your `ViewModel`. You would also probably want to add more null and error checking in or around the service call method.

One important part that I left out of this is Google's Requirement that the Google logo show up when searches are being performed. So download [their icon](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/policies#logo_requirements) and add it to the UI. I only display it when the user is focused on the `Entry`.

So these are the Places models and my own `Address` model:

```
public class AddressInfo {

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }

    public string ZipCode { get; set; }

    public double Longitude { get; set; }

    public double Latitude { get; set; }
}

public class PlacesMatchedSubstring {

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("length")]
    public int Length { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("offset")]
    public int Offset { get; set; }
}

public class PlacesTerm {

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("offset")]
    public int Offset { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Prediction {

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("matched_substrings")]
    public List<PlacesMatchedSubstring> MatchedSubstrings { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("place_id")]
    public string PlaceId { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("reference")]
    public string Reference { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("terms")]
    public List<PlacesTerm> Terms { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("types")]
    public List<string> Types { get; set; }
}

public class PlacesLocationPredictions {

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("predictions")]
    public List<Prediction> Predictions { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Here we call the Places API:

```
public const string GooglePlacesApiAutoCompletePath = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key={0}&input={1}&components=country:us"; //Adding country:us limits results to us

public const string GooglePlacesApiKey = "bTafrOPmO4LpPgAl34r5wQ6LFRWhgTxBW80-3GK";

private static HttpClient _httpClientInstance;
public static HttpClient HttpClientInstance => _httpClientInstance ?? (_httpClientInstance = new HttpClient());

private ObservableCollection<AddressInfo> _addresses;
public  ObservableCollection<AddressInfo> Addresses {
    get => _addresses ?? (_addresses = new ObservableCollection<AddressInfo>());
    set {
        if(_addresses != value) {
            _addresses = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    };
}

private string _addressText;
public  string AddressText {
    get => _addressText;
    set {
        if(_addressText != value) {
            _addressText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    };
}

public async Task GetPlacesPredictionsAsync() {

    // TODO: Add throttle logic, Google begins denying requests if too many are made in a short amount of time

    CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)).Token;

    using(HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, string.Format(GooglePlacesApiAutoCompletePath, ConstantKeys.GooglePlacesApiKey, WebUtility.UrlEncode(_addressText)))) { //Be sure to UrlEncode the search term they enter

        using(HttpResponseMessage message = await HttpClientInstance.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false)) {
            if(message.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
                string json = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                PlacesLocationPredictions predictionList = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlacesLocationPredictions>(json)).ConfigureAwait(false);

                if(predictionList.Status == "OK") {

                    Addresses.Clear();

                    if(predictionList.Predictions.Count > 0) {
                        foreach(Prediction prediction in predictionList.Predictions) {
                            Addresses.Add(new AddressInfo {
                                Address = prediction.Description
                            });
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new Exception(predictionList.Status);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now for the UI...

```
    <Entry Text="{Binding AddressText}"
           TextChanged="OnTextChanged" />

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Addresses}">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextCell Text="{Binding Address}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

And code behind:

```
private async void OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) {
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewModel.AddressText)) {
        await ViewModel.GetPlacesPredictionsAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, and if may I ask, how do you get the coordinates? do you use geocoder?

Comment: @MauricioCárdenas Coordinates from the `Prediction` class? If so, yes. I use the Google Geocode API. Pretty much the same code except I use the geocode URL for the service call and I deserialize the response into different models.

Comment: @hvaughan3 is this line: await ViewModel.GetAddressCoordinatesAsync(); should be calling GetPlacesPredictionsAsync?

Comment: @MauricioCárdenas Yes, good catch. Ill fix it. Also fixed the `OnTextChanged` method name.

Comment: @hvaughan3 I have a question: there's this "SetPropertyChanged" that I cannot find anywhere else, so it throws error: "The name 'SetPropertyChanged' does not exist in the current context".  Could you help me out with that please?

Comment: @MauricioCárdenas That is a custom method. You will instead want to us `OnPropertyChanged();`. Check out [this](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-binding/) link and search for `OnPropertyChanged` on that webpage to see how it works. I will edit my post

Comment: @hvaughan3 You're the real MVP

Comment: In the UI code there is a word "Text" which gives the error "Unable to cast object of type 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ListNode' to type 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IElementNode'"  Ohh it took around 3hours to figure out why is that error!

Comment: @hvaughan3 i got sometimes Index was outside the bounds of the array.' or index out of range on addresses.Add but i don't really know why. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @MatDev8 Can you put some try/catches around the code and see which line it is throwing that on? My example uses a foreach so its unlikely it would throw that exception. Are you using a for loop perhaps?

Comment: @hvaughan3 I used the same code. I just add the try catch but it not hit, the exception occure on te adresses.Add line. The probleme is that not happened each time i launch my app...so really hard to understand. I thought it was link task or something look to thread access