# How to implement Google PlaceAutocompletePrediction in Xamarin forms? Complete code example?

Tags: xamarin.forms, google-places-api

I have been struggling for days to implement what should be straightforward code. I want to request users to enter their location. And in location entry, I want to have predictions of the addresses based on the user's typed text. There are not many videos online on that topic. I have seen the links shown below. However, not one of them is related to Xamarin Forms or Google api PlaceAutocompletePrediction of addresses.

Would any expert be willing to provide complete logic from scratches regarding the matter?

[This code example is showing an error 'An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'member' in below part of the code for (ServiceClass1.AddressText)) and await ServiceClass1.GetPlacesPredictionsAsync();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34390423/google-place-autocomplete-in-xamarin-forms)

```
private async void Entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ServiceClass1.AddressText))
            
        {
            await ServiceClass1.GetPlacesPredictionsAsync();
        }
    }
```

[Not what I am looking for](https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/146114/autocomplete-google-places)

[Not what I am looking for](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDfiPNgRuBQ)

[Incomplete code](https://www.xamboy.com/2019/05/29/google-maps-place-search-in-xamarin-forms/)

Comment: Checkout my answer to a similar question
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45747263/3850012

Comment: Hi @hvaughan3, I found your answer, which is the closest and detailed answer available online regarding the matter. I tried to implement it. I was following your code fully. However, It is showing an error 'An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'member' in the final part of the code for (ServiceClass1.AddressText)) and await ServiceClass1.GetPlacesPredictionsAsync();
I referenced it above as a link and the code in which line the error is occurring. This is your code referenced above :)

Any ideas why the error is occurring?

Comment: Hmm i am still using that code today and do not have that issue. Is that a build or runtime error?

Comment: I am not sure. Because when it did not work, a tried different method. Which works. But now I need to figure out how to display this list on UI when text changed. Do you mind to check this question and perhaps offer a solution please ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69497439/how-can-i-display-in-ui-a-list-of-predictions-from-my-backend-code-when-text-c