# How can I display in UI a list of predictions (from my backend code when 'Text_Changed' in the user's entry? Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, user-interface, xamarin.forms, data-binding

my backend code with places autosuggestion works well (I can see it reads the locations from the list in my backend)
Now I want to show that list to users when he/she starts to type something in entry by using Text_Changed option.
Below is my Text_Changed method ("locationText_Changed"). Now how to show the Prediction list to a user in UI when he/she starts to type some text?

Backend code:

```
private async void locationText_Changed(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (location == null)
        {
            await GetLocation();
        }
        string formattedLocation = string.Format("{0}%2C{1}", location.Latitude, location.Longitude);
        List<Prediction> predictionList = await VenueLogic1.GetVenues1(e.NewTextValue, formattedLocation);
```

And my UI:

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="BlanchedAlmond" >
                <Entry x:Name="locationEntry"
                   TextChanged="locationText_Changed"
                   Placeholder="Enter Address"/>
            </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use databinding and collectionview/listview, set the ItemsSource as your predictionList, then change the itemsSourece in locationText_Changed method.like:

```
    private async void locationText_Changed(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (location == null)
            {
                await GetLocation();
            }
            string formattedLocation = string.Format("{0}%2C{1}", location.Latitude, location.Longitude);
            List<Prediction> predictionList = await VenueLogic1.GetVenues1(e.NewTextValue, formattedLocation);
var newlist=from n in predictionList where n.contains(text)
select n;
mycollectionlist.ItemsSource=newlist;}
```

Comment: Thanks, with Item source as you suggested it works well.

Comment: Zhu. can you help me with related question regarding itemTapped, which is described in following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69526490/how-can-i-populate-the-search-bar-field-item-source-with-data-from-the-listvie

Comment: It seems like it has been solved

Answer (score 2):

First: To you show this list you need to use a `ListView` (it's better in questions of performance);

Second: The entry could be a `SearchBar`.

So, what you can do:

- Create a searchBar, the user will input some data on it.
- While the user is typing, your code will filtering the list and only will appear what matches with the input (as you mentioned).

In [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/searchbar) it shows step by step of how to achieve it. So maybe you will change something in your code, but the result is professional.

PS: Try to do it only following this link. If has any doubt, please, update your question with what you did and we will help you. Have fun.

Comment: Please, if this answer solves the problem, accept this answer with the green mark to close it. You're welcome!