# How can I populate the Search bar field (Item Source) with data from the ListView when the ListView ItemTapped? XAMARIN FORMS

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I created a Entry that shows addresses in the list view when text changed. It works well. Now I want to implement ItemTaped to populate the Entry to save that data (as I am saving/binding Entry results). I know how to do it for only one string (name), but I have 2 strings in my code (string search-changing text and string location-string formatedLocation in code name).
Below is my code. So my question is how to write a code for ItemTapped(searchResults_ItemTapped-in code name) in order to ListView data populate my Entry field (locationText_Changed- in code name)? Thanks.

```
 private async void locationText_Changed(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {           
        if (location == null)
        {
            await GetLocation();
        }
        string formattedLocation = string.Format("{0}%2C{1}", location.Latitude, location.Longitude);
        List<Prediction> predictionList = await VenueLogic1.GetVenues1(e.NewTextValue, formattedLocation);      
            searchResults.ItemsSource = predictionList;
            
        } catch (NullReferenceException nulrex)
        {
        } catch (Exception except)
        {
        }
    }
    private void searchResults_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

UI:

```
<Entry x:Name="locationEntry"
                       TextChanged="locationText_Changed"
                       Placeholder="Unesi Lokaciju"/>                  />
                    <ListView x:Name="searchResults" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" ItemTapped="searchResults_ItemTapped" >
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding description}"/>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a reference to `locationEntry` by name, and you can use pattern matching to type check and cast `ItemTappedEventArgs.Item` to your search result type, then grab the description from that object.

```cs
private void searchResults_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is MySearchResultClass result)
    {
        locationEntry.Text = result.description;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is working perfectly. Thanks :)

Comment: Great! Consider marking it as the accepted answer for others in the future.